# Using Jasypt for password based AES encryption with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 key

Tags: java, aes, encryption-symmetric, pbkdf2, jasypt

I'm implementing an encryption mechanism where I work, and the security guy's demands are as follows:

1. Create a 256 bit key using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512, secret password, 256bit salt and 20000 iterations minimum.
2. Salt should be generated using SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
3. Encrypt using AES256 with the derived key.

I'm trying to use Jasypt's *StandardPBEStringEncryptor* class

```
encryptor.setPassword(PASSWORD);
encryptor.setAlgorithm("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
encryptor.setKeyObtentionIterations(20000);
encryptor.setSaltGenerator(new RandomSaltGenerator());
encryptor.encrypt("something");
```

When I do this I get the following exception:

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding SecretKeyFactory not available

Am I using Jasypt incorrectly? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: If the security guy is recommending password encryption in any way shape or form he should be replaced. The whole idea is radically insecure. Passwords must be hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: It's not for user passwords, just for some configuration properties such as database username, database passwords etc.
It's data that's only passed within our intranet and is encrypted for extra security not as a first line of defense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up contacting Daniel Fernández who is Jasypt's lead programmer and his answer:

> I’m afraid Jasypt does not offer a way to specify different algorithms for the SecretKeyFactory and the instantiation of the Cipher itself. Sorry.

I used this bit of java code for doing this (Without Jasypt):

```
public String encrypt(final String message) {
  final byte[] salt = generateSalt();
  final Key key = createKey(salt);

  final Cipher encryptingCipher = createCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, salt);
  final byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  final byte[] encryptedBytes = doFinal(encryptingCipher, messageBytes);
  final byte[] data = ArrayUtils.addAll(salt, encryptedBytes);
  return BaseEncoding.base64().encode(data);
}

private byte[] generateSalt() {
  final SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
  final byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
  secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
  return salt;
}

private Key createKey(final byte[] salt) {
  final PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD,
                                       salt,
                                       ITERATIONS,
                                       KEY_LENGTH);
  final SecretKey secretKey;
  try {
    secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec);
  } catch (final InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error creating SecretKey", e);
  }
  final SecretKeySpec result = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM);
  spec.clearPassword();
  return result;
}
```